# Magento import a foreign key constrain fails

Tags: database, magento, import, foreign-keys

I am trying to import my live database to an test database. While importing the tables to the test database im getting the following error.

MySQL: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DB_Name`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON )

I have set the SET Foreign_Key_Checks but it seems this isn't changing the error at all.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
//Code
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Do i need to change table names or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

This command is not only used when you import but also when you export live db you need to execute this command then export file. create new database execute this command and try to import database.

Comment: I have checked disable foreign keys checks when i exported the database. Im going to try this for the second time.

Comment: Is the Disable Foreign keys the same as SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; While exporting the database or do i need to run that command first and disable foreign keys and export the live database?